# What if question owner gets the bounty?

Tags: support, bounty, self-answer

I have read quite a bit about bounties. If someone puts up a bounty on someone elses question, and they answer the question and award the bounty to themselves, then I know that they will get 0 rep points.

**But, what happens if** someone puts a bounty on another question, and the owner of the question answers the question. Will they also get 0 rep points? Because it is not the owner of the question who knows about the bounty...Right?

**I made this diagram for the question**

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The bounty cannot be awarded to answers posted *by whomever created the bounty*. It doesn't matter who asked the question.

In other words, if the bounty was set by someone other than the person asking the question, then a self-answer posted by the author of the question can be awarded the bounty.